# How to find out the key field for a nhibernate object

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-metadata

Say I have the following query

```
ICriteria query = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
```

How can I find out the key field of T so that I can add an expression like so

```
query.Add(Expression.In(keyField, someListOfObjects.ToArray()));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NH's meta data

```
var meta = factory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(T));

query.Add(Expression.In(meta.IdentifierPropertyName, someListOfObjects.ToArray()));
```

Comment: @Mark: Yes, SessionFactory point to the ISessionFactory you used to create the session.